# Why taking screenshot with System.IO doesn't work?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I've added to my game screenshot feature. Build it in Xcode, but got ""FileNotFoundException: Could not find file" error. Why?

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
{

    string imageName = "LevelFinished" + current_level.ToString() + ".png";

    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + imageName);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + imageName);
    Texture2D screenshotTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    screenshotTexture.LoadImage(data);
    Sprite screenshotSprite = Sprite.Create(screenshotTexture, new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));

    UI_Image_final.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = screenshotSprite;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot.html) for ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot I missed "On mobile platforms the filename is appended to the persistent data path" part. That means, that my path for saving screenshot was incorrect; therefore I had to change only one line:

```
//ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + imageName);
//Change for:
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(imageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html):

> Contains the path to a persistent data directory (**Read Only**).

If this is correct, means that your screenshot can't be stored there, so if you check your persistentDataPath directory, you won't find the picture. Try to remove the part of the code that loads the texture, and just try to store it, then check if the file is there.

One way to store that kind of stuff could be using the folder [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) to store the screenshots. I know, the documentation says:

> On many platforms, the streaming assets folder location is read-only

But I've made a test and at least for Windows and Android, it will let you write and read from that folder.